# Java - Multi Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I got this question in an interview, can some one clarify it..

```
**/**
 * Assuming a threaded environment, and without knowing anything else,
 * what is the potential problem with myMethod()?
 * Fix it in the simplest way.
 */
*/
public class ClumsyTest {
    private static final String FUBAR = "fubar";

    public boolean myMethod(final MyObject bar) {
        if (bar.getFoo() != null) {
            return bar.getFoo().equals(FUBAR);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public interface MyObject {
        String getFoo();
        void setFoo(String o);
    }
}**
```

in 'myMethod', bar.getFoo() was verified twice. In multi thread environment, it is very well possible that value can change. So, we need to verify it only once, and if we write as below,

```
 **if (bar.getFoo().equals(FUBAR)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }**
```

it will throw null pointer exception if bar.getFoo() is null.

How can we fix this method to check only once and by avoiding null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple actually.

Rather than doing `bar.getFoo().equals(FUBAR)` which risks `NullPointerException`, you gotta check it other way around as `FUBAR.equals(bar.getFoo())`. And that's all there is to it.

So simply

```
    public boolean myMethod(final MyObject bar) {
        
        return FUBAR.equals(bar.getFoo());
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the accepted answer. However, it works only for this specific case where `equals()` is used. Had any other method of `bar.getFoo()` been used, we would not have been able to avoid the possible `NullPointerException` in the same way.

The more generic answer is to store the result in a local variable.

```
public boolean myMethod(final MyObject bar) {
    
    Object temp = bar.getFoo(); // temp can obviously be a more specific type
    if (temp != null) {
        return temp.toString().equals(FUBAR);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```